# Installing openjdk-6-jre:i386 on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit: broken dependencies

Tags: package-management, openjdk

I wa strying to install **openjdk-7-jre:i386** in order to access to the university's VPN.
I've a machine with *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (precise) 64 bit*. However, when I try to install openjdk-6-jre:i386,

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre:i386
```

I end up with this error:

```
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto 
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Alcuni pacchetti non possono essere installati. Questo può voler dire
che è stata richiesta una situazione impossibile oppure, se si sta
usando una distribuzione in sviluppo, che alcuni pacchetti richiesti
non sono ancora stati creati o sono stati rimossi da Incoming.
Le seguenti informazioni possono aiutare a risolvere la situazione:

I seguenti pacchetti hanno dipendenze non soddisfatte:
 openjdk-6-jre:i386 : Dipende: libatk-wrapper-java-jni:i386 (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) ma 
 non sta per essere installato
E: Impossibile correggere i problemi, ci sono pacchetti danneggiati bloccati.
```

which basically says that there are some packages that have unsatisfied dependencies:

```
The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies:
 openjdk-6-jre:i386 : dipends on: libatk-wrapper-java-jni:i386 but it cannot be installed
E: Impossible to correct problems, there are damaged bloked packages.
```

Any hint on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install openjdk-7 but uses command for openjdk-6,
For JRE use this

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

For JDK use this

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: I need the open-jdk-jre:i386 version, which actually has unsatisifed/broken dependencies.

Comment: This is the i386 version and openjdk documentation(http://openjdk.java.net/install/) says to install like this